# Grails installation

Tags: linux, grails, ubuntu, groovy

I am trying to install Grails from sources.
I started 3 days ago, and still have some problems.
Every attempt finishes with message:

```
:grails-bootstrap:compileGroovy
[ant:groovyc] >>> a serious error occurred: grails/util/BuildSettings
[ant:groovyc] >>> stacktrace:
[ant:groovyc] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/util/BuildSettings
[ant:groovyc]   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[ant:groovyc]   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2440)
[ant:groovyc]   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1806)
Execution failed for task ':grails-bootstrap:compileGroovy'.
> Forked groovyc returned error code: 1
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

What I did:

1. Install java

   java version "1.7.0-ea"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-ea-b76)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b05, mixed mode)
2. Install groovy

   Groovy Version: 2.0.0 JVM: 1.7.0-ea Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
3. Clone grails and checkout it to v2.1.0
4. Invoke sudo ./gradlew install

if I use --stacktrace --info --debug

```
00:15:19.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
00:15:19.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
00:15:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
00:15:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':grails-bootstrap:compileGroovy'.
00:15:19.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Forked groovyc returned error code: 1
00:15:19.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
00:15:19.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
00:15:19.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':grails-bootstrap:compileGroovy'.
00:15:19.792 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
00:15:19.794 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
00:15:19.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
00:15:19.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
00:15:19.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
00:15:19.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
00:15:19.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
```

What can I do better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be using the wrong version of groovy -- I'm pretty sure it's 1.8.6.

Comment: Yep, grails isn't moving to groovy 2.0 [till grails 2.2](http://grails.org/Roadmap)